# I cant run this, line 39: Mismatched input 'stopLossLongSaved' expecting 'end of line without line continuation

Tags: pine-script

I have this code, but I cant make it run.
When I check says  line 38: Mismatched input 'stopLossLongSaved' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

This is the code :

```
//New day calculation 
var stopLossLongSaved = 0.0
var takeprofitLongSaved= 0.0
var stoplossShortSaved= 0.0
var takeprofitShortSaved= 0.0
newDay=change(time("D"))

if newDay
    if strategy.position_size==0
      stopLossLongSaved := stopLossLong
      takeprofitLongSaved :=takeprofitLong
      strategy.entry(id='Long',long=strategy.long, stop =buyPoint, oca_name='x', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)     
 stoplossShortSaved :=stopLossShort
      takeprofitShortSaved :=takeprofitShort
      strategy.entry(id='Short', short=strategy.short, stop=sellPoint, oca_name='x', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)


//Exit after sl or tp is hit
strategy.exit(id='LongExit',from_entry='Long',limit=takeprofitLongSaved, stop=stopLossLongSaved)
strategy.exit(id='ShortExit', from_entry='Short', limit= takeprofitShortSaved, stop= stoplossShortSaved)

//Draw data to chart
plot(dailyHigh, color=blue, line=2,title='DailyHigh'))
plot(dailylow, color=red, line=2,title='DailyLow'))
plot(buyPoint, color=purple, title='Buypoint'))
plot(sellPoint, color= yellow,  title='Sellpoint'))
plot(stopLossLong, color=red, title='Long Stop Loss'))
plot(takeprofitLong, color= green, title='Takeprofit Long'))
plot(takeprofitShort, color= red, title= 'Takeprofit Shor'))
plot(stopLossShort, color= orange, title='Stop Loss Short'))
```

Comment: If what we see is exactly how your code is written, `stoplossShortSaved :=stopLossShort` is breaking the if block and the next two lines are written as if they were in the if block. Please share your whole code.

Comment: stackoverflow dont let me post all the code, but is this  <https://codeshare.io/0ge6Y8>

Answer (score 0):

There were many issues with your code.

The biggest ones were:

- For indentation, you must use 4 spaces or 1 tab
- Colors have `color.x` namespace now (e.g. `color.red`)
- Input types have `input.x` namespace now (e.g. `input.float`)

Here is your fixed code:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title = " Brakeout Strategy v1.0",  overlay = true,  default_qty_value = 100000)

// pips

entryPips= input(title="Entry pips",defval= 3.0, type=input.float, tooltip="Pips to place order")
stopPips= input(title='Stop pips', defval=5.0, type=input.float, tooltip="Pips to stop")
targetPips= input(title='Target pips',defval=10.0, type=input.float, tooltip='Takeprofit')

//High and low
dailyHigh= security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", high)
dailylow= security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)

//buy and sell
buyPoint= dailyHigh+(entryPips*10*syminfo.mintick)
sellPoint=dailylow-(30*syminfo.mintick)


//stoploss 
stopLossLong= buyPoint-(stopPips*10*syminfo.mintick)
stopLossShort=sellPoint- (stopPips*10*syminfo.mintick)


//take profit
takeprofitLong=buyPoint+(targetPips*10*syminfo.mintick)
takeprofitShort=sellPoint+(targetPips*10*syminfo.mintick)

//New day calculation 
var stopLossLongSaved = 0.0
var takeprofitLongSaved= 0.0
var stoplossShortSaved= 0.0
var takeprofitShortSaved= 0.0
newDay=change(time("D"))

if newDay
    if strategy.position_size==0
        stopLossLongSaved := stopLossLong
        takeprofitLongSaved :=takeprofitLong
        strategy.entry(id='Long',long=strategy.long, stop =buyPoint, oca_name='x', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
        stoplossShortSaved :=stopLossShort
        takeprofitShortSaved :=takeprofitShort
        strategy.entry(id='Short', long=strategy.short, stop=sellPoint, oca_name='x', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
  
//Exit after sl or tp is hit
strategy.exit(id='LongExit',from_entry='Long',limit=takeprofitLongSaved, stop=stopLossLongSaved)
strategy.exit(id='ShortExit', from_entry='Short', limit= takeprofitShortSaved, stop= stoplossShortSaved)


//Draw data to chart
plot(dailyHigh, color=color.blue, title='DailyHigh')
plot(dailylow, color=color.red, title='DailyLow')
plot(buyPoint, color=color.purple, title='Buypoint')
plot(sellPoint, color=color.yellow,  title='Sellpoint')
plot(stopLossLong, color=color.red, title='Long Stop Loss')
plot(takeprofitLong, color=color.green, title='Takeprofit Long')
plot(takeprofitShort, color=color.red, title= 'Takeprofit Short')
plot(stopLossShort, color=color.orange, title='Stop Loss Short')


plot(close)
```